# How to make a checksum.dat hash file from a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, file, text, hash, checksum

I'm trying to make a file called checksum.dat which contains the SHA256 hash of a file called index.txt in Python.

What I've come up with so far:

```
import hashlib
with open("index.txt", "rb") as file3:
    with open("checksum.dat", "wb") as file4:
        file_checksum = hashlib.sha256()
        file_checksum.update(file3)
        file_checksum.digest()

        print(file_checksum)
        file4.write(file_checksum)
```

I want it to print the hash into the console and also write it into the checksum.dat file.

But all I get is this error:

```
File "...", line 97, in main
file_checksum.update(file3)
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

What I've googled so far is that you cannot make a hash out of a string, from my understanding, only from byte objects or something. No idea how to make my index.txt into an object I can use.

Anyone know how to fix this? Bear in mind I'm a newbie.

Comment: which Python version are you working on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to feed the contents of `index.txt`, so the problem lies here:

```
file_checksum.update(file3)
```

`file3` is file pointer to the `index.txt` file and it does not have the content of the file. To get the contents, do `read()`. So following should fix it:

```
file_checksum.update(file3.read())
```

So, your complete code would be:

```
import hashlib
with open("index.txt", "rb") as file3:
        file_checksum = hashlib.sha256()
        for line in file3:
            file_checksum.update(line)
            file_checksum.hexdigest()
        print(file_checksum.hexdigest())

with open("checksum.dat", "wb") as file4:        
        file4.write(bytes(file_checksum.hexdigest(), 'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Now I get the following exception:

`file4.write(file_checksum)

TypeError: '_hashlib.HASH' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: Don't read the whole file at once, otherwise your program will choke on large inputs. Also, don't use `encode()`, since it might alter the original representation (and the hash code).

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo - updated the answer, now it reads line by line and calculates the checksum. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Almost works, it puts "ý?±zªíº™K[²!A‹¨Ñ†N$ŠJ…¾•«gx­Ž" into the checksum.dat file, but we were given a correct solution, which would be: "14ca7e2ff65628dc515d43aea8029d623701a164cc6282ce1444550420b46fa3" in the checksum.dat file.